# hex string to list or array of int in python2/3 without testing python version and without loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, int, hex

I need to convert an hex string to list or array of int in python2/3 without testing python version or loop :

`s='c951ede6'`

`expectedResult = '[201,  81, 237, 230]'`

expectedResult can be an array or a list

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `binascii`

```
import binascii

s='c951ede6'

new_s = binascii.unhexlify(s)
#for python 3:
expectedResult = list(new_s)

#for Python2:
expectedResult = map(ord, mew_s)
```

Output:

```
[201, 81, 237, 230]
```

Comment: Your `list(map(ord, s))` does not work with Python3, it only works in Python2. Python3 returns `TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found`

Comment: The pb. is I don't want any loop (see title)

Comment: In python3, you get a list of int but in python2 you get :
`['\xc9', 'Q', '\xed', '\xe6']`, sorry.

Comment: @SebMa No problem. In Python2, map over the list with ord(). In Python3, cast `new_s` to a list. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: The pb. is that this piece of code is already in a long loop, if you double check the title, it says : "... without testing python version" :-)

Comment: @SebMa I do not believe there is a universal solution when it comes to the `binascii` module. May I ask why you cannot know the Python version for this project. I may be able to shed light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [int(s[i:i+2], 16) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
```

There is no actual way of doing such a thing "without a loop". You could push the loop to native code, but them it is not "in Python".

Answer (score 0):

@Ajax1234

First let me thank you for the `unhexlify` part because I do need it.
For the second, I figured a way to make it portable with numpy for both python2 and 3.
Here is the whole code :

```
import binascii

import numpy as np

s='c951ede6'

new_s = binascii.unhexlify(s)

expectedResult = np.fromstring( new_s, dtype=np.uint8 )
```